# Get Object Notification for Google Cloud Storage Using pub/sub

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I want to notify my script whenever a new object is uploaded to my bucket. I have created a bucket, created a topic, and configured the subscription. (Follow [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/notification_polling.py))

However, my script is waiting and not getting any notifications.

Here is my code:

```
poll_notifications('bold-proton-236611', 'projects/bold-proton-236611/subscriptions/processphotos')

def poll_notifications(project, subscription_name):
    """Polls a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription for new GCS events for display."""
    # [BEGIN poll_notifications]
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    print('Received message:\n{}'.format(summarize(message)))
    message.ack()

subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

# The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
# exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
# [END poll_notifications]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this now with Cloud Functions.... not sure if that's what you're looking for.

On the Create Function UI, you can select "Cloud Storage" as the Trigger.

Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I am sending audio to my bucket, I want my  python script to be notified if object uploaded to the bucket , please redirect me to the article, tutorial if you know any I searched a lot